# how to run selenium with python in cgi

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, cgi

I am trying to run this code on my webserver

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
phantomjs_path = "/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path,service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
browser.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5)
search_box = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

But the browser shows the following message

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Simple scripts are working fine like printing a html document which means that my configuration is correct.
This is my error log:

```
[Fri Sep 25 14:36:28.909899 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 922:tid 139922897643392] (2)No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/selenium-working.py' failed
[Fri Sep 25 14:36:28.910837 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 1245:tid 139922702849792] [client 127.0.0.1:58791] End of script output before headers: selenium-working.py
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try line by line so you can dedect error line.

Comment: How do i do that on the server?

Comment: comment out all your lines and remove one by one. at least, you would know to where you get error